# J1 to F1 after a gap- am I non resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

I was on J1 (research scholar) visa in 2009 and 2010. Then I stayed out of US and came back on F1 student visa in 2015 and held the F-1 student visa for 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019. My question is for the 2019 tax year, am I a resident alien or non-resident alien?

Answer (score 1):

You were an "exempt individual" (exempt from the Substantial Presence Test) as a "teacher or intern" (which includes any J1 who is not a student) for your time on J1 in 2009 or 2010, since for neither year were you an exempt individual for some part of 2 of the previous 6 calendar years.

You were an "exempt individual" as a student for your time on F1 as long as you have not been an exempt individual of some part of 5 previous calendar years. So you would be an exempt individual for your time on F1 in 2015, 2016, and 2017. For 2018 and 2019, you would not be an exempt individual for any part of the time you were on F1, because you had already been an exempt individual for some part of 5 previous calendar years (2009, 2010, 2015, 2016, and 2017). So all your days of presence in the US in 2018 and 2019 are counted in the Substantial Presence Test, and (assuming you were in the US for most of the year), you are a "resident alien" for tax purposes for 2018 and 2019.